# Mathematica: How to prevent evaluation of In[-1]?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When I'm trying to get last input expression in Wolfram *Mathematica* 5.2 using `In[-1]` I get evaluated output:

```
In[1]:= On[In]
2 + 2
In[-1]

Out[2]= 4

During evaluation of In[1]:= In::trace: In[-1] --> In[$Line-1]. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= In::trace: In[$Line-1] --> In[2]. >>

During evaluation of In[1]:= In::trace: In[2] --> 2+2. >>

Out[3]= 4
```

How can I get the input expression in unevaluated form?

Comment: I haven't got the slightest idea in what sort of language or program you are trying to accomplish this.

Comment: @Michel It is Wolfram _Mathematica_ 5.2. This was in the tag and now in the header and the body of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `InString[]`

```
In[1]:= 2 + 2
Out[1]= 4

In[2]:= InString[-1]
Out[2]= "\\(2 + 2\\)"
```

Comment: Thank you. `DisplayForm@ToExpression[InString[-1]]` works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way:

```
In[1]:= 2 + 2
With[{line = $Line - 1}, HoldForm[In[line]] /. DownValues[In]]

Out[1]= 4

Out[2]= 2+2
```

**Edit:**

This method does not work properly with `Unevaluated`:

```
In[1]:= Unevaluated[2 + 2]
With[{line = $Line - 1}, HoldForm[In[line]]] /. (DownValues[In])
Out[1]= Unevaluated[2 + 2]
Out[2]= 2 + 2
```

I have opened a [`separate question on this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036907/how-to-make-an-analog-of-instring).