# Question on Condition (/;)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

`Condition` has attribute `HoldAll` which prevents evaluation of its first argument before applying the `Condition`. But for some reason `Condition` evaluates its first argument even if the test gives `False`:

```
In[1]:= Condition[Print[x],False]
During evaluation of In[1]:= x
Out[1]= Null/;False
```

Why is this? For what purposes `Condition` evaluates its first argument if the test gives `False`? In which cases this behavior can be useful?

P.S. Its behavior differs when the `Condition` is used as the second argument of `SetDelayed`:

```
In[5]:= f:=Condition[Print[x],False]; f
Out[6]= f
```

This is what I expected for the all cases.

Comment: @Mr.wizard good morning/afternoon/evening/night! @Alexey I don't know about HoldAll but isn't Condition supposed to work on patterns, RuleDelayed and SetDelayed only, not anything else? At least, that's what in the docs. Your usage is undocumented.

Comment: @Sjoerd I understand but in *Mathematica* all the functions are supposed to be working in a very general way.

Comment: As you possibly know, Ted Ersek discusses [here](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_A-K_19.html) an unrelated subtlety of `Condition` (and a use of `Update`).  The [reply](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2005/Oct/msg00208.html) of Carl Woll to an old Mathgroup question from David Park might also be of general interest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I can tell (and this has been mentioned by other answerers already), `Condition` should not be thought of as a standalone function, but as a wrapper used in forming larger expressions involving patterns. But I want to stress that part of the subtlety here comes from the fact that `Rule` and `RuleDelayed`  are scoping constructs. In general, scoping constructs must have a variable-binding stage, where they resolve possible conflicts in variable names and actually bind variables to their occurrences in the body of the scoping construct (or, in the r.h.s. of the rule for `Rule` and `RuleDelayed`). This may be considered a part of the inner workings of the scoping constructs, but, because Mathematica allows top-level manipulations through attributes and things like `Evaluate`, scoping constructs are not as black-box as they may seem - we may change the bindings by forcing the variable declarations, or the body, or both, to evaluate before the binding happens - for example, by removing some of the `Hold*` - attributes. I discussed these things [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/May/msg00206.html) in somewhat more detail, although, not knowing the exact implementation details for the scoping constructs, I had to mostly guess.

Returning back to the case of `Rule`, `RuleDelayed` and `Condition`, it is instructive to `Trace` one of the examples discussed:

```
In[28]:= Trace[Cases[{3,3.},a_:>Print[a]/;(Print["!"];IntegerQ[a])],RuleCondition,TraceAbove->All]
During evaluation of In[28]:= !
During evaluation of In[28]:= !
During evaluation of In[28]:= 3

Out[28]= {Cases[{3,3.},a_:>Print[a]/;(Print[!];IntegerQ[a])], 
{RuleCondition[$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[Print[3]]],True],
      $ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[Print[3]]]},
{RuleCondition[$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[Print[3.]]],False],Fail},
 {Print[3]},{Null}}
```

What you see is that there are special internal heads `RuleCondition` and `$ConditionHold`, which appear when `Condition` is used with `Rule` or `RuleDelayed`. My guess is that these implement the mechanism to incorporate conditions on pattern variables, including the variable binding. When you use `Condition` as a standalone function, these don't appear. These heads are crucial for condition mechanism to really work.
You can look at how they work in `Rule` and `RuleDelayed`:

```
In[31]:= RuleCondition[$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[Print[3.`]]],True]
Out[31]= $ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[Print[3.]]] 

In[32]:= RuleCondition[$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[Print[3.`]]],False]
Out[32]= Fail
```

You can see that, say, `Cases` picks up only elements of the form `$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[something]]`, and ignore those where `RuleCondition` results in `Fail`.   Now, what happens when you use `Condition` as a stand-alone function is different - thus the difference in results.

One good example I am aware of, which illustrates the above points very well, is in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/3a5ae92bda1c7511), where possible implementations of a version of `With` which binds sequentially, are discussed. I will repeat a part of that discussion here, since it is instructive. The idea was to make a version of With, where previous declarations can be used for declarations further down the declaration list. If we call it `Let`, then,  for example, for code like

```
Clear[h, xl, yl];
xl = 1;
yl = 2;
h[x_, y_] := Let[{xl = x, yl = y + xl + 1}, xl^2 + yl^2];
h[a, b]
```

we should get

```
a^2+(1+a+b)^2
```

One of the implementations which was suggested, and gives this result, is:

```
ClearAll[Let];
SetAttributes[Let, HoldAll];
Let /: (lhs_ := Let[vars_, expr_ /; cond_]) := 
   Let[vars, lhs := expr /; cond]
Let[{}, expr_] := expr;
Let[{head_}, expr_] := With[{head}, expr]
Let[{head_, tail__}, expr_] := With[{head}, Let[{tail}, expr]]
```

(this is due to Bastian Erdnuess). What happens here is that this `Let` performs bindings at run-time, rather than at the time when function is being defined. And as soon as we want to use shared local variables, it fails:

```
Clear[f];
f[x_,y_]:=Let[{xl=x,yl=y+xl+1},xl^2+yl^2/;(xl+yl<15)];
f[x_,y_]:=x+y;

?f
Global`f
f[x_,y_]:=x+y
```

Had it worked correctly, and we should have ended up with 2 distinct definitions. And here we come to the crux of the matter: since this `Let` acts at run-time, `SetDelayed` does not perceive the `Condition` as a part of the pattern - it would do that for `With`, `Block`, `Module`, but not some unknown `Let`. So, both definitions look for Mathematica the same (in terms of patterns), and therefore, the second replaces the first. But this is not all. Now we only create the first definition, and try to execute:

```
Clear[f];
f[x_, y_] := Let[{xl = x, yl = y + xl + 1}, xl^2 + yl^2 /; (xl + yl < 15)];

In[121]:= f[3, 4]

Out[121]= 73 /; 3 + 8 < 15
```

If you trace the last execution, it would be very unclear why the `Condition` did not fire here. The reason is that we messed up the binding stage. Here is my improved version, which is free from these flaws:

```
ClearAll[LetL];
SetAttributes[LetL, HoldAll];
LetL /: Verbatim[SetDelayed][lhs_, rhs : HoldPattern[LetL[{__}, _]]] :=
   Block[{With}, Attributes[With] = {HoldAll};
     lhs := Evaluate[rhs]];
LetL[{}, expr_] := expr;
LetL[{head_}, expr_] := With[{head}, expr];
LetL[{head_, tail__}, expr_] := 
  Block[{With}, Attributes[With] = {HoldAll};
    With[{head}, Evaluate[LetL[{tail}, expr]]]];
```

What is does is that it expands `LetL` into nested `With` at definition-time, not run-time, and that happens *before* the binding stage. Now, let us see:

```
In[122]:= 
Clear[ff];
ff[x_,y_]:=LetL[{xl=x,yl=y+xl+1},xl^2+yl^2/;(xl+yl<15)];

Trace[ff[3,4]]

Out[124]= {ff[3,4],       
{With[{xl$=3},With[{yl$=4+xl$+1},RuleCondition[$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[xl$^2+yl$^2]],
 xl$+yl$<15]]],With[{yl$=4+3+1},RuleCondition[$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[3^2+yl$^2]],3+yl$<15]],
{4+3+1,8},RuleCondition[$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[3^2+8^2]],3+8<15],
{{3+8,11},11<15,True},RuleCondition[$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[3^2+8^2]],True],
$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[3^2+8^2]]},3^2+8^2,{3^2,9},{8^2,64},9+64,73}
```

This works fine, and you can see the heads `RuleCondition` and `$ConditionHold` showing up all right. It is instructive to look at the resulting  definition  for `ff`:

```
?ff
Global`ff
ff[x_,y_]:=With[{xl=x},With[{yl=y+xl+1},xl^2+yl^2/;xl+yl<15]]
```

You can see that `LetL` has expanded at definition-time, as advertised. And since pattern variable binding happened after that, things work fine. Also, if we add another definition:

```
ff[x_,y_]:=x+y;

?ff
Global`ff
ff[x_,y_]:=With[{xl=x},With[{yl=y+xl+1},xl^2+yl^2/;xl+yl<15]]

ff[x_,y_]:=x+y
```

We see that the patterns are now perceived as different by Mathematica.

The final question was why `Unevaluated` does not restore the behavior of `RuleDelayed` broken by the removal of its `HoldRest` attribute. I can only guess that this is related to the unusual behavior of `RuleDelayed` (it eats up any number of `Unevaluated` wrappers around the r.h.s.), noted in the comments to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036907/how-to-make-an-analog-of-instring).

To summarize: one of the most frequent intended uses of `Condition` is closely tied to the enclosing scoping constructs (`Rule` and `RuleDelayed`), and one should take into account the variable binding stage in scoping constructs, when analyzing their behavior.

Comment: Gosh Leonid, you sure write a lot!  Maybe you should consider writing a book or something...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't know of a good *and* short example to illustrate my point, and besides, these are rather subtle issues that I don't completely understand myself. Regarding the book, thanks for the hint, already considered :)

Comment: Knowing the details of the mission of the `RuleCondition` and `$ConditionHold` all these things would be MUCH more clear and easy expressible. Thanks for this great analysis, I need some time to understand it. One note on the mission of the `Condidtion`: if the `Condition` is not a standalone function it looks like a defect that it ever works when is called as a standalone function. It should stay unevaluated according to its attribute `HoldAll`!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sure I did, but the truth is that I also would prefer a shorter explanation, just like shorter code. @Alexey's comment is right on target - had we known more about this stuff, we would probably be able to find shorter ways to explain it.

Comment: @Alexey  As @Mr.Wizard has demonstrated, there can be productive uses of this behavior. And as we all know, `HoldAll` does not imply that the function does not evaluate the argument, but merely that the function is in a position to decide whether or not to evaluate it.

Comment: @Leonid How the `Condition` can be classified in accordance with [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheMeaningOfExpressions.html) documentation page? Does it match the listed  interpretations at all? Are there other symbols with such behavior of a semi-wrapper -- semi-function?

Comment: @Alexey I'd say it is a *Head*. I would not consider it a function. Of course, all this classification is subjective. Mathematica does not need it, we do. And I think this is what makes mma so powerful - the fact that expressions are so general that they can be used for such different purposes or their combinations.

Comment: @Alexey `$ConditionHold` _seems_ straightforward: to Hold `Condition`.  And it does (at least) that:  `$ConditionHold[Print["!"] /; False]`  I suspect that it is used rather than Hold simply so that it can selectively be addressed or released.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'd guess that `$ConditionHold` is actually just a `HoldAll` - carrying wrapper with a special name (known to certain functions like `Cases` etc), and not much else. And it seems to hold not the condition, but the code to execute if condition is satisfied. I may be wrong of course.

Comment: Leonid, that is what I was working my way toward, but again you said it better.  That's what happens when I keep editing these comments.  Ping . pong . ping . pong ... ;-)

Comment: @Mr. Wizard - funny, I also thought of ping-pong. I just thought we reached the limitation of SO way of doing things, should switch to a chat, and perhaps a collaboratively-edited web-based mma front-end would be a good addition ? :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I knew about the site, but I did not know that one can execute mma code right on the page. Still, this falls a bit short of the level of interactivity I meant.

Comment: Sorry, I should have acknowledged that it was not nearly what you meant, but what you said made me think of that site, and I wondered if it might be useful in some (other) way.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My understanding is that that site serves a different purpose, more like a collaboratively-edited hub for mma-related links, files and other resources, and it seems quite useful.

Answer (score 5):

`Condition` use often depends on what is in the left hand side, so it must evaluate the LHS at least to some degree.  Consider:

```
MatchQ[3, a_ /; IntegerQ[a]]
```

```
   True
```

```
p = {a_, b_};

MatchQ[{3, 0.2}, p /; IntegerQ[a] && b < 1]
```

```
   True
```

Both for this and from this, I would have guessed that `Condition` had attribute `HoldRest` rather than `HoldAll`.  It probably needs `HoldAll` for some internal use, perhaps related to the `SetDelayed` usage.

Comment: With attribute `HoldRest` the [Villegas-Gayley's trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656) would not be possible as well as right behavior in such cases as `Cases[{3, 3.}, a_ :> Print[a] /; IntegerQ[a]]`.

Comment: @Alexey, isn't the `Cases` example because of `RuleDelayed` rather than a Hold attribute of `Condition`?  I think the "trick" could fall into the special handling of `/;` within `:=` that you illustrated.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You are right. `Unprotect[Condition];
ClearAttributes[Condition, HoldAll];
Cases[{3, 3.}, a_ :> Print[a] /; IntegerQ[a]]` does not change the behavior mentioned. It seems that when the `Condition` is placed inside of the second argument of `RuleDelayed` and `SetDelayed` and probably `TagSetDelayed` and `UpSetDelayed` works in completely different way than  by default. It is interesting that in the case of `RuleDelayed` it works differently even is placed inside of the first argument: `Cases[{3, 
  3.}, (Print["!"]; a_) /; IntegerQ[a] :> (Print[a] /; IntegerQ[a]; 
   Print["!!"])]`.

Comment: @Alexey, placement is indeed unusual about `/;` and different people have different conventions about where to put it.  If you clear attributes for `/;` and then try:  `Cases[{3, 3.}, a_ /; IntegerQ[a] :> Print[a]]` you see it fails, because `IntegerQ[a]` evaluates to `False`.

Comment: I have made a mistake in the above comment: inside of the first argument of `RuleDelayed` the behavior of `Condition` is the same: the first argument is evaluated for the first time and only `a_` stays as the first argument of `Condition` for the future calls to `Condition` from `Cases`. It seems that it is because of internal optimizations of `Cases`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You mean by "different people" different developers?

Comment: @Alexey, yes, that's all I meant.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The `HoldRest` attribute of `RuleDelayed` is important: `Unprotect[RuleDelayed]; ClearAttributes[RuleDelayed, HoldRest]; Cases[{3, 3.}, a_ :> Print[a] /; (Print["!"]; IntegerQ[a])]`. The unusual side is that the default behavior cannot be restored by `Unevaluated`: `Unprotect[RuleDelayed]; ClearAttributes[RuleDelayed, HoldRest];
Cases[{3, 3.}, a_ :> Unevaluated[Print[a] /; (Print["!"]; IntegerQ[a])]]`.